# how to run a java program stored in sub directory from another java program in the current folder

Tags: java, jar, classpath, exec

I have big problem, please help me My situation is this, i have program RegAlloc.java, that uses several classes that is another packages P1 and P2. RegAlloc.java and these 2 packages are in a folder called Temp1. Temp is folder that contains Temp1 and Simplify.java, this folder also contains Pacjages named P! and P2 i needs to run RegAlloc from Simplify.java is there any solution? i am using the Linux platform, pls help me

```
try{
    String s="RegAlloc.class";
    String[] cmd = {"java", "-classpath=home/koha/pjt_new/Temp/Temp1/", s};

    Process pro2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new nputStreamReader(pro2.getInputStream()));

    String line = null;
    System.out.println(in.readLine());

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        text+=line;
        text+="\n";
    }
    System.out.println(text);

} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("not Okey");
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear. And what is the error you are getting ? And from what I can understand String s="RegAlloc.class" should be String s="RegAlloc"

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the classpath variable and then run the program

Where I have the classes like as follows

1. COne class is in Package P1
2. CTwo Class is in Pakcage P2
3. Your Current folder is like F1 which contains COne.java and CTwo.java;

Compile the classes in the following manner.

```
javac -d . *.java
```

The above command will create two subdirectories in your current folder with the names P1 and P2 and the respective .class files will be pushed automatically

Set the Classpath environmental variable as :

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;./P1;/P2;.
```

And Run Your Program like

```
java P1.COne
```