# when executing a program in subdirectory , exec command in java is not working well

Tags: java

I have to execute a program `RegAlloc.jav`a with input redirection (`4.miniIR` file)

```
try{
    String s="java  -classpath MiniRA/ RegAlloc < MiniRA/4.miniIR";
    Process pro2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
    BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro2.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        text+=line;
        text+="\n";
        System.out.println(text);
    }
    System.out.println(text);
  }
catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("not Okey");
}
```

but I don't get the proper result; the output window is just displayed and will not terminate the program.  Can anybody help me find the error?

Comment: How does your new question differ from the [one you asked 40mins ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158586/redirection-in-exec-method-in-java)?

Comment: [They](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116465/how-to-execute-a-java-program-using-another-java-program-stored-in-a-sub-directo) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134496/how-to-run-a-java-program-stored-in-sub-directory-from-another-java-program-in-t) [everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158586/redirection-in-exec-method-in-java)!

Comment: @n.st That explains `it urgent for me.. :(`

Comment: @devnull There are even answers and comments on some of the duplicates, but Akhi Youngisthan never replied to any of them...

Comment: @n.st you're really after him eh? lol he has asked the same question 4 times, rephrasing it each time ever so slightly...

Comment: Sorry frnds, it was a big probelm to me, and i solved it

String s="java  -classpath MiniRA/ "+pgmname+" "+menuFrame.filename;  
  
 Process pro2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro2.getInputStream()));

Answer (score 0):

if its just regarding the process is not terminated, you can force terminate it using `pro2.destroy()` in the code, at the end of try block.

Answer (score 0):

You must read from `stdin` in your process. But you try hook `stdin` of external process. Try replace it:

```
BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```